# C# ShockWave Flash Object does not exist in COM COMPONENTS

Tags: c#, shockwave, axshockwaveflash

I will get videos from youtube and other websites into c# winform application.  I need Shockwave Flash Object in Com Components and I installed Adobe Shockwave Player and Adobe Flash Player. Just Shockwave ActiveX Control appeared. [image]

No ShockWave Flash Object. Can someone tell me that - What should I install to get that component to visual stuido?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by installing Flash Player version 19 which I downloaded from [this link](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html#fp15).